# Task chaining in JavaFX8: Start next Task after onSucceeded finished on previous task

Tags: concurrency, javafx-8

I'm rather new to JavaFX8 and facing the following problem. In my current App, which is for document processing/editing, I have two rather expensive tasks. Opening a document and saving a document.

My app has the buttons "import next", "export current" and "export current and import next". For Import and Export, I have two Task of the following structure:

```
    private class Export extends Task<Void> {
    public Export() {
        this.setOnRunning(event -> {
            // do stuff (change cursor etc)
        });

        this.setOnFailed(event -> {
            // do stuff, eg. show error box
        });

        this.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            // do stuff
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        // do expensive stuff
        return null;
    }
}
```

I submit the task using the `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`.

For the functionality "export current and import next", my goal is to submit the Export and Import tasks to the executor, but my Import tasks should only run if the export-task was sucessful and the EventHandler given in `setOnSucceedded` (whichs runs on the GUI thread) finished. If the export fails, it does not make any sense to load the next document because user interaction is needed. How can this be achieved?

First I tired to but the entire logic/error handling in the `call` method, but this does not work as I cannot change the GUI from this method (i.e. to show an error-box).

As workaround, I'm manually submitting the import-task on the last line of my `setOnSucceeded` in the export-task, but this is not very flexible, because I want to be sure this task exports only (without subsequent import)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't call the handler property methods `setOnXXX` in your `Task` subclass constructor. These actually set a property on the task, so if you also call those methods from elsewhere you will replace the functionality you're implementing in the class itself, rather than add to it.

Instead, override the protected convenience methods:

```
public class Export extends Task<Void> {

    @Override
    protected void succeeded() {
        super.succeeded();
        // do stuff...
    }

    @Override
    protected void running() {
        super.running();
        // do stuff...
    }

    @Override
    protected void failed() {
        super.failed();
        // do stuff...
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() {
        // do expensive stuff....
        return null ;
    }
}
```

Now you can safely use `setOnXXX(...)` externally to the `Export` class without breaking its functionality:

```
Export export = new Export();
export.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
    Import import = new Import();
    executor.submit(import);
});
executor.submit(export);
```

This puts the logic for chaining the tasks at the point where you actually create them, which would seem to be the correct place to do it.

Note that another way to provide multiple handlers for the change of state is to register listeners with the `stateProperty()`:

```
Export export = new Export();
export.stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

From testing, it appears the order of execution of these different mechanisms is:

1. state listeners
2. the `onSucceeded` handler
3. the `Task.succeeded` method

All are executed on the FX Application Thread.

So if you want the code in the `Task` subclass to be executed *before* the handler added externally, do

```
public class Export extends Task<Void> {

    public Export() {
        stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == Worker.State.RUNNING) {
                // do stuff
            } else if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                // do stuff
            } else if (newState == Worker.State.FAILED) {
                // do stuff
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Finally, you could implement the entire logic in your `call` method: if you need to interact with the UI you can wrap those calls in a `Platform.runLater(() -> {});`. However, separating the functionality into different tasks as you have done is probably cleaner anyway.

Comment: in your example, does the lines in "setOnSucceeded()" overwrites the code given before in "succeedded()"? Or iin which order are they executed?

Comment: It does not replace the code in the `succeeded()` method. From a quick test, it seems the handler `setOnSucceeded()` is executed first. Both are executed on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: ok, then it does not really solve to problem because the next task should be submitted after the code provided in the definition of the task (ie. in your succeeded()-method) finished